# Stored Procedure can you check it?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, insert

I've created a stored procedure to insert infos into my intermediate table [PropositionProduit]. I'm not sure if I did it right, because I receive my data from my view and when I insert it into my database I've no error and my data isn't inserted.

Thanks for your help!

IdAdresse and IdUtilisateur I receive from my session.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_DonateProduct_Insert]

    @nameProduct NVARCHAR(100),
    @datePeremption Date,
    @quantite INT,
    @description NVARCHAR(200),
    @bio bit,
    @nomMarque NVARCHAR(150),
    @pays NVARCHAR(50),
    @labelEtat NVARCHAR(50),
    @title NVARCHAR(50),
    @src NVARCHAR(250),
    @labelType NVARCHAR(50),
    @dateProposition date,
    @dateFin date,
    @idAdresse INT,
    @idUtilisateur INT

AS
DECLARE @idMarque INT, @idEtat INT, @idPhoto INT, @idType INT, @idProduit INT

    INSERT INTO[Marque]([Nom], [Pays])
    VALUES (@nomMarque, @pays)
    SET @idMarque= @@IDENTITY

    INSERT INTO[Etat]([Label])
    VALUES (@labelEtat)
    SET @idEtat= @@IDENTITY

    INSERT INTO[Photo]([Title], [Src])
    VALUES (@title,@src)
    SET @idPhoto= @@IDENTITY

    INSERT INTO[Type]([Label])
    VALUES (@labelType)
    SET @idType = @@IDENTITY

    INSERT INTO[Produit]([Nom], [DatePeremption],[Quantite], [Description], [Bio], [IdMarque], [IdType], [IdEtat], [IdPhoto], [IdAdresse])
    VALUES (@nameProduct, @datePeremption, @description, @quantite, @bio, @idMarque, @idType, @idEtat, @idPhoto, @idAdresse)
    SET @idProduit= @@IDENTITY

    INSERT INTO[PropositionProduit]([IdUtilisateur], [IdProduit], [DateProposition], [DateFin] )
    OUTPUT inserted.IdProposition
    VALUES (@idUtilisateur, @idProduit, @dateProposition, @dateFin)

RETURN 0
```

[image]

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: Depending on your dbms and configuration "Auto Commit" may be turned off, in which case you must manually commit the inserts.  For example by adding the command "COMMIT" after your last insert,

Comment: I use SSMS. Actually I've already made another stored procedure to insert infos about my user and it works. So, for you my stored procedure is correct ?